# Are there any other uses for "Clear Sky"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

During Skyrim's Main Quest you're given the 3 words and knowledge to perform the shout "*Clear Sky*" which is required to

> reach the *Throat of the World* where Paarthurnax is.

The shout is used in this part to clear away the fog which saps at your health but i am wondering, outside of this can Clear Sky be used for anything else, i've tried shouting at the sky when it was raining at Riverwood but it didn't do anything (apart from making me look like an idiot and embarrassing my wife Lydia)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Clear Sky got two usages as far as i know:

1. Using it changes the weather to sunny. When you have Auriels Bow, its extremely useful when you cant see the sun.
2. There are some poisontraps around the map, mostly in dwemerruins (e.g. in markarth below the laboratory of calcelmo). The shout will remove the poison, making it possible to walk through it without taking damage.

Answer (score 1):

Clear sky should indeed clear rain/snow/fog/cloud. It might not be useable in certain areas like Winterhold.

Cleaing the rain/snow/etc can help you see things better, and it can help you if you have certain mods involved that debuffs you during these things (eg. Frostfall/Hypothermia).

Furthermore, Clear sky can be used in the final sets of missions in the main quest. It can be used to clear Alduin's soul snaring fog, as well as his meteor shower shout.

Comment: Also if you are playing with mods like Frostfall/Hypothermia etc it helps to get it to stop snowing/raining.

Comment: I'll add it in.

Answer (score 0):

It changes the weather to sunny. If it doesn't work the first time, try again. Try the single-word shout first, and then the full three-word shout. That should instantly clear all the skies.